# Delete query in cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

```
Delete delete = QueryBuilder.delete()
  .from("addresbook", "contact")
  .where(eq("username", "dgarcia"));
```

what is the type of "eq" in where clause

[Delete example here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/reference/queryBuilder_r.html)

Comment: you can refer this http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/1.0/com/datastax/driver/core/querybuilder/QueryBuilder.html#eq(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import static com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.QueryBuilder.eq;
```

Cheers,
Carlo